# node.js, express.js - res.render does not work in safari, shows html source as plain text

Tags: node.js, safari, express

I try to res.render('mytemplate', data), works fine in all browsers except Safari (incl. iOS), Safari does not render and shows html in plain text, also some header info:

```
HTTP/1.1 success unknown
X-Powered-By: Express
content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 4489
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=pSY62z68tPe4TnQBLuhBPaVZ.Hd7o0jSkf%2F4AztPcwxhwoWgeqbIggMBrRfRHV3L7G0g; path=/; expires=Tue, 14 Feb 2012 05:27:49 GMT; httpOnly
Connection: keep-alive

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->

    ...

</html>
```

This is how I do the rendering:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
res.render('myTemplate', data);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

solved it:

```
res.render(myTemplate, data,
    function(err, rendered) {
        // console.log(rendered);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(rendered);
     });
```

thx for listening ...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought, but judging by the fact that it's Safari that is complaining, could it be that the content-type header is all lower case, and not the proper `Content-Type`? Try that...

Edit: I see by your other answer that the problem was the 200 OK...